# spring social twitter user search by query

Tags: twitter, spring-social

I'm using Spring Social Twitter to display list of users based on a criteria lets say screenname. How do I pass the criteria in query? When I pass screen_name=test, it display all the records not specific.

```
 twitter.userOperations().searchForUsers("screen_name=test");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve the user profile for a specific user other than the authenticated user, you can so do by passing the user's screen name as a parameter to getUserProfile():

```
TwitterProfile profile = twitter.userOperations().getUserProfile("habuma");
```

But this is only if your criteria is for example the screen name. What other criteria do you have in mind?

Comment: How can a make cutom queries? like get all the users which work for company A?